# Does stage3d use OpenGL? or Direct3D when on Windows

Tags: opengl, webgl, stage3d

WebGl is based on OpelGL ES 2.0.
Is it correct to say that Stage3d is also based OpenGL? I mean does it call OpenGL functions? Or ot calles Direct3D when runs on Windows?

If no, could you explain me, what API does Stage3d use for hardware acceleration?

Comment: `WebGL` is not a `JavaScript` binding to `OpenGL`. `WebGL` is a 3D Graphics API simply based on `OpenGL ES 2.0` and uses a `HTML5 Canvas Element` to render upon also using all the GPU features which can be used through the browser.

Comment: WebGL also ties up a few loose ends with respect to buffer overruns and other security issues. Whereas GL and GL ES favor performance and leave certain security issues undefined, WebGL has to go out of its way to make sure these things cannot be exploited. It is not clear how much performance is lost with WebGL's added baggage, but it is definitely worth mentioning.. I have a feeling that any responsible browser-based 3D API that layers itself on top of D3D, OGL, etc. is going to have these added constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, Stage3D isn't based on anything, it may share similar methodology/terminology. It is another rendering pipeline, this is why Adobe is soo pumped about it.

Have a look at this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html 
You can skip down to this heading "Comparing the advantages and restrictions of working with Stage3D" to get right down to it.

Also, take a peak at this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html, excerpt:

> The Stage3D APIs in Flash Player and Adobe AIR offer a fully
>   hardware-accelerated architecture that brings stunning visuals across
>   desktop browsers and iOS and Android apps enabling advanced 2D and 3D
>   capabilities.  This set of low-level GPU-accelerated APIs provide
>   developers with the flexibility to leverage GPU hardware acceleration
>   for significant performance gains in video game development, whether
>   you’re using cutting-edge 3D game engines or the intuitive, lightning
>   fast Starling 2D framework that powers Angry Birds.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incorrect unfortunately. Stage 3D uses:

- DirectX on Windows systems
- OpenGL on OSX systems
- OpenGL ES on mobile
- Software Renderer when no hardware acceleration is available. (Due to
  older hardware or no hardware at all.)

Please see: http://www.slideshare.net/danielfreeman779/adobe-air-stage3d-and-agal